# TSQL filtering by character match

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

How to filter out number of count matches without building new user functions(i.e. you can use built-in functions) on a given data?

The requirement is to get rows with the gw column numbers appearing the same amount of times or if there is different set of amounts their number must match the other ones count. I.e. it could be all 1 like the Sandy's or it could be Don since it has '1' two times and '2' two times as well. Voland would not meet the requirements since he has '1' two times but only once '2' and etc. You don't want to count '0' at all.

```
login      gw1 gw2 gw3 gw4 gw5
Peter       1   0   1   0   0
Sandy       1   1   1   1   0
Voland      1   0   1   2   0
Don         1   2   0   1   2
```

Diserid output is:

```
login      gw1 gw2 gw3 gw4 gw5
Peter       1   0   1   0   0
Sandy       1   1   1   1   0
Don         1   2   0   1   2
```

Values could be any positive number of times. To match the criteria values also has to be at least twice total. I.e. 1 2 3 4 0 is not OK. since every value appears only once. 1 1 0 3 3 is a match.

Comment: Can there be other values than 0, 1 and 2?

Comment: Yes it could be any number but '0'

Comment: So is "1, 2, 3, 4, 0" supposed to be returned or not? (One of each, same number!)

Comment: No, I have added extra explanation on the original question. The total number of appearance have to be at least twice.

Comment: What do you mean by without using functions?

Comment: pivot, group by, count in (2,4)

Comment: Don doesn't have 2 twice. He's got 3 x 1. Is this a typo?

Comment: Was a typo on a desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fb82f/1/0)

```
WITH Cte(login, gw) AS(
    SELECT login, gw1 FROM TestData WHERE gw1 > 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT login, gw2 FROM TestData WHERE gw2 > 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT login, gw3 FROM TestData WHERE gw3 > 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT login, gw4 FROM TestData WHERE gw4 > 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT login, gw5 FROM TestData WHERE gw5 > 0
),
CteCountByLoginGw AS(
    SELECT
        login, gw, COUNT(*) AS cc
    FROM Cte
    GROUP BY login, gw
),
CteFinal AS(
    SELECT login
    FROM CteCountByLoginGw c
    GROUP BY login
    HAVING
        MAX(cc) > 1
        AND COUNT(DISTINCT gw) = (
                SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM CteCountByLoginGw 
                WHERE 
                    c.login = login 
                    AND cc = MAX(c.cc)
        )
)
SELECT t.*
FROM CteFinal c
INNER JOIN TestData t
    ON t.login = c.login
```

---

First you `unpivot` the table without including `gw` that are equal to 0. 
The result (`CTE`) is:

```
login      gw
---------- -----------
Peter      1
Sandy      1
Voland     1
Don        1
Sandy      1
Don        2
Peter      1
Sandy      1
Voland     1
Sandy      1
Voland     2
Don        1
Don        2
```

Then, you perform a `COUNT(*) GROUP BY login, gw`. The result would be (`CteCountByLoginGw`):

```
login      gw          cc
---------- ----------- -----------
Don        1           2
Peter      1           2
Sandy      1           4
Voland     1           2
Don        2           2
Voland     2           1
```

Finally, only get those `login` whose `max(cc)` is greater `1`. This is to eliminate rows like `1,2,3,4,0`. And `login` whose unique `gw` is the same the `max(cc)`. This is to make sure that the occurrence of a `gw` column is the same as others:

```
login      gw1         gw2         gw3         gw4         gw5
---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Peter      1           0           1           0           0
Sandy      1           1           1           1           0
Don        1           2           0           1           2
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party, I can't type as fast as some and I think I arrived about 40 minutes late but since I done it, I thought I'd share it anyway.
My method used unpivot and pivot to achieve the result:

```
Select * 
from foobar f1
where exists 
(Select * from
(Select login_, Case when [1] = 0 then null else [1] % 2 end Val1, Case when [2] = 0 then null else [2] % 2 end Val2, 
Case when [3] = 0 then null else [3] % 2 end Val3, Case when [4] = 0 then null else [4] % 2 end Val4, Case when [5] = 0 then null else [5] % 2 end Val5
from
(Select *
from
(select * from foobar) src
UNPIVOT
(value for amount in (gw1, gw2, gw3, gw4, gw5)) unpvt) src2
PIVOT
(count(amount) for value in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) as pvt) res
Where 0 in (Val1,Val2, Val3, Val4, Val5) and not exists (select * from foobar where 1 in (Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, Val5)) and login_ = f1.login_)
```

and here is the fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b78f8/1/0

Answer (score 0):

I think this logic is correct, viz

<del>Find the rows where there is at least one even number of equal `gws` and no instance of odd number of `gws`. Zeroes are excluded</del>

> Find the rows where there is at least one number of equal `gws` and no instance of a single `gws`. Zeroes are excluded.

Unpivot is used to simplify reasoning over the `gwx` columns, and CTEs are used to prevent repetition.

```
WITH unpvt AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM MyTable
    UNPIVOT 
    (
        gwvalue
        for z in (gw1, gw2, gw3, gw4, gw5)
    ) x
),
grp AS
(
    SELECT [login], gwvalue, COUNT(gwvalue) gwCount
    FROM unpvt 
    WHERE gwvalue > 0
    GROUP BY [login], gwvalue
)
SELECT 
* 
FROM MyTable mt
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM grp g
    WHERE g.[login] = mt.[login]
    AND gwCount > 1
)
AND NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM grp g
    WHERE g.[login] = mt.[login]
    AND gwCount = 1
);
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8c32/3)

Comment: It is not about odd or even numbers, the main criteria is to have at least two 'number of times', i.e. > 1 and if there is two those match that criteria they have to be both the same total amount of appearance. 1 0 1 2 2 is ok since '1' appears twice so and '2' appears twice. Could be any numbers like 10 10 0 15 15, it is still an OK.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. I've updated accordingly.